# Find all the filenames in this directory that do not contain 'a' 'b' or 'c' in their name

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, filenames

I am trying to find all the files in my directory that does not contain the letters a,b or c; why does this command not work?

```
ls *[!abc]*
```

example:     eg: MATCH: xyz, dkh, file, foo; NOT MATCH: bar, bxc, azi,csk

Comment: Would you please add more description. In addition, example and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command does something very similar to what you want: it expands to the list of filenames that are *not* exactly: `a`, `b`, or `c`. If you test, you see:

```
$ touch a b c d
$ ls *[!abc]*
d
```

But if you create another file and re-test:

```
$ touch argh
$ ls *[!abc]*
argh d
```

To exclude file names that contain those characters anywhere, use:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls !(*[abc]*)
d
```

Another way of doing it (again with extended globs) would be to explicitly list out the patterns:

```
$ ls !(*a*|*b*|*c*)
d
```